# Where is the file for the apache default open directory display

Tags: apache

With Apache it is possible to have the settings such that when a user requests access to a directory and that directory does not contain any index file then Apache displays a default directory listing as shown in the attached image.

Can anybody tell me where that default directory listing file resides? I would like to modify it for responsive design as well as adding Google analytics code.

I am getting responsive design warnings from Google Webmaster tools on the WordPress uploads directories. I don't want to block them but in fact would like search engines to crawl and index them. With that being said, I also don't want to get mobile usability errors on the same.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best way is to use the `.htaccess` file to gain control over directory listings with Apache. This website has a bunch of good stuff to look through: https://perishablepress.com/better-default-directory-views-with-htaccess/

Generally, I would recommend specifically creating `index.html` files or something to specifically control what users/search engines are seeing, but obviously modifying the default directory listing has benefits.

You can use `HeaderName` and `ReadmeName` to supply customised HTML for the header and footer of the directory listings:

```
# SPECIFY HEADER FILE
HeaderName header.html

# SPECIFY FOOTER FILE
ReadmeName footer.html
```

**Note:** Be sure to also set `IndexOptions +SuppressHTMLPreamble` if you are specifying a custom header & footer to stop Apache adding the default `<html>`, `<head>` and `<body>` elements!

Comment: I added the HeaderName code to .htaccess and also created the header.html file. Now when I browse to that open directory and view source code I can see that the code is in fact there. The only thing I observed is that my code from the new header.html is not actually within the head section but is below it and inside the body tags. Is it possible to get my new code to reside inside of those existing head tags?

Comment: You will want to set `IndexOptions +SuppressHTMLPreamble` as well to specify your own `<html>`, `<head>`, `<body>` etc. I'll update the answer.

Answer (score 1):

There isn't a file per se. The HTML is embedded in the [C source code for mod_autoindex](https://github.com/apache/httpd/blob/fd4276cb10e07a7a1c7f4472c31ca7bad908c07e/modules/generators/mod_autoindex.c).

You can't achieve some limited control over the output with [the mod_autoindex configuration options](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_autoindex.html), most useful of which will probably be [the HeaderName Directive](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_autoindex.html#headername)

```
HeaderName /path/to/index_header.html
```

… but if you want serious control over the output, then you are probably looking at writing your own server side program to replace mod_autoindex.